# GetFrontBufferData to video memory and not system memory

Tags: graphics, directx, directx-9

Using DirectX 9 I want to capture what is on the screen and display a smaller version of it in my program.

To capture it I found and am using GetFrontBufferData. However the way it works is by writing to a surface defined in system memory (D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM). This results in my having to then transfer the screen shot back into video memory so I can then draw it.

As you can imagine this needless transfer from (video memory -> System memory -> video memory) causes quite a shutter in my program.

Is there a way I can get the image stored in the front buffer and put it onto a surface in video memory?

This question is a spin off of my recent question : [Capture and Draw a ScreenShot using DirectX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518214/capture-and-draw-a-screenshot-using-directx)

Comment: Do you want to display it PIP?  Because your PIP will be part of the frame buffer.  I don't think there is any quicker way to get at the frame buffer, put a PIP inside it, and then *not* have the PIP show up inside the PIP etc.

Comment: I want it to display picture in picture. I want to get a copy of the front buffers data (Crop it to an area I want to focus on) and then draw it in the back buffer. 

Having the Pip NOT show in the Pip area was not part of the requirements. I have been been entertained by the "endless hallway" effect but for my final product the Pip area to be displayed will be a subset of the entire screen that will not encompass the Pip area.

Comment: In that case, what's stopping you from 1) rendering the scene to frame buffer, 2) rendering the same (or subset) to a RenderTarget surface, 3) draw the surface to the frame buffer?

Comment: Because I am not generating the scene I want captured? I am capturing an area that is outside of my application. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Hhhmmm... in that case, I don't think there is a simpler way to do it than you're already doing it right now.

Comment: Yes, that's my research has been turning up... Seems in earlier version of DirectX you could get direct access to the FrontBuffer via a pointer to it but they have moved away from this idea and made it more "Secure"

Comment: Not really.  That's because GPU's started getting sophisticated, and things like automatic FSAA and multisampling make it difficult to be sure of the format of the frame buffer, because it may not even have the same number of pixels as exposed to the program.